# inApp Update, download but not installed

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with inapp update. A new version window appears, when you press the "Update now" button, unfortunately nothing happens, the application downloads in the background, but nothing happens app is not updated. I would like to add that I am testing it on the "Open Test" in play store path.

```
    private void checkForUpdate() {
        appUpdateManager
            .getAppUpdateInfo()
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                appUpdateInfo -> {

                    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
                    if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
                            && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE))
                    {
                        // Request the update.
                        try {
                            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                    appUpdateInfo,
                                    AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
                                    this,
                                    REQUEST_APP_UPDATE);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `FLEXIBLE` method for updating the App, which will download the app but will not auto-update it.

You have to monitor the flexible update progress and once the update is downloaded, you have to install it manually.

```
     private val installStateUpdatedListener = InstallStateUpdatedListener { state ->
            when (state.installStatus()) {
                InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED -> completeUpdate()
                InstallStatus.FAILED -> reportUpdateFailure(state.installErrorCode())
                else -> {
                    // Right now we only care about download success / failed state
                }
            }
        }

// Before starting an update, register a listener for updates.
appUpdateManager.registerListener(listener)

// Start an update.

// When status updates are no longer needed, unregister the listener.
appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(listener)
```

Once the update is downloaded, you have to call `appUpdateManager.completeUpdate()` to complete the update.

You can get more information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#flexible

Comment: Ok its works, thanks! but im have another problem after install. When the app restarts after installation, I can't force it to go into background mode (home button) when it wants to do back to the foreground actions, the application starts from the beginning.